# Find an object in a JSON array in mySQL database using javascript with a filter

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, discord.js

In my mysql database I have a model with the current format: 
`id: text`
`pokemons: JSON`
`pc: JSON`
Here's one as an example:

```
{
  id: '430368553787719692',
  pokemons: '["{\\"name\\":\\"houndoom\\",\\"types\\":[\\"dark\\",\\"fire\\"],\\"stats\\":[75,90,50,110,80,95],\\"moves\\":[{\\"name\\":\\"curse\\",\\"type\\":\\"ghost\\",\\"power\\":null,\\"accuracy\\":null,\\"priority\\":0,\\"statChanges\\":null},{\\"name\\":\\"solar-beam\\",\\"type\\":\\"grass\\",\\"power\\":120,\\"accuracy\\":100,\\"priority\\":0,\\"statChanges\\":null},{\\"name\\":\\"facade\\",\\"type\\":\\"normal\\",\\"power\\":70,\\"accuracy\\":100,\\"priority\\":0,\\"statChanges\\":null},{\\"name\\":\\"odor-sleuth\\",\\"type\\":\\"normal\\",\\"power\\":null,\\"accuracy\\":null,\\"priority\\":0,\\"statChanges\\":null}],\\"sprite\\":\\"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/229.png\\",\\"color\\":\\"black\\",\\"isLegendary\\":false,\\"isMythical\\":false}", "{\\"name\\":\\"electivire\\",\\"types\\":[\\"electric\\"],\\"stats\\":[75,123,67,95,85,95],\\"moves\\":[{\\"name\\":\\"light-screen\\",\\"type\\":\\"psychic\\",\\"power\\":null,\\"accuracy\\":null,\\"priority\\":0,\\"statChanges\\":null},{\\"name\\":\\"natural-gift\\",\\"type\\":\\"normal\\",\\"power\\":null,\\"accuracy\\":100,\\"priority\\":0,\\"statChanges\\":null},{\\"name\\":\\"captivate\\",\\"type\\":\\"normal\\",\\"power\\":null,\\"accuracy\\":100,\\"priority\\":0},{\\"name\\":\\"electroweb\\",\\"type\\":\\"electric\\",\\"power\\":55,\\"accuracy\\":95,\\"priority\\":0}],\\"sprite\\":\\"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/466.png\\",\\"color\\":\\"yellow\\",\\"isLegendary\\":false,\\"isMythical\\":false}", "{\\"name\\":\\"exeggcute\\",\\"types\\":[\\"grass\\",\\"psychic\\"],\\"stats\\":[60,40,80,60,45,40],\\"moves\\":[{\\"name\\":\\"absorb\\",\\"type\\":\\"grass\\",\\"power\\":20,\\"accuracy\\":100,\\"priority\\":0,\\"statChanges\\":null},{\\"name\\":\\"psychic\\",\\"type\\":\\"psychic\\",\\"power\\":90,\\"accuracy\\":100,\\"priority\\":0},{\\"name\\":\\"worry-seed\\",\\"type\\":\\"grass\\",\\"power\\":null,\\"accuracy\\":100,\\"priority\\":0,\\"statChanges\\":null},{\\"name\\":\\"toxic\\",\\"type\\":\\"poison\\",\\"power\\":null,\\"accuracy\\":90,\\"priority\\":0,\\"statChanges\\":null}],\\"sprite\\":\\"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/102.png\\",\\"color\\":\\"pink\\",\\"isLegendary\\":false,\\"isMythical\\":false}", "{\\"name\\":\\"voltorb\\",\\"types\\":[\\"electric\\"],\\"stats\\":[40,30,50,55,55,100],\\"moves\\":[{\\"name\\":\\"hidden-power\\",\\"type\\":\\"normal\\",\\"power\\":60,\\"accuracy\\":100,\\"priority\\":0,\\"statChanges\\":null},{\\"name\\":\\"eerie-impulse\\",\\"type\\":\\"electric\\",\\"power\\":null,\\"accuracy\\":100,\\"priority\\":0},{\\"name\\":\\"magic-coat\\",\\"type\\":\\"psychic\\",\\"power\\":null,\\"accuracy\\":null,\\"priority\\":4,\\"statChanges\\":null},{\\"name\\":\\"thunder-wave\\",\\"type\\":\\"electric\\",\\"power\\":null,\\"accuracy\\":90,\\"priority\\":0,\\"statChanges\\":null}],\\"sprite\\":\\"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/100.png\\",\\"color\\":\\"red\\",\\"isLegendary\\":false,\\"isMythical\\":false}", "{\\"name\\":\\"glastrier\\",\\"types\\":[\\"ice\\"],\\"stats\\":[100,145,130,65,110,30],\\"moves\\":[{\\"name\\":\\"endure\\",\\"type\\":\\"normal\\",\\"power\\":null,\\"accuracy\\":null,\\"priority\\":4,\\"statChanges\\":null},{\\"name\\":\\"stomp\\",\\"type\\":\\"normal\\",\\"power\\":65,\\"accuracy\\":100,\\"priority\\":0,\\"statChanges\\":null},{\\"name\\":\\"close-combat\\",\\"type\\":\\"fighting\\",\\"power\\":120,\\"accuracy\\":100,\\"priority\\":0},{\\"name\\":\\"scary-face\\",\\"type\\":\\"normal\\",\\"power\\":null,\\"accuracy\\":100,\\"priority\\":0}],\\"sprite\\":\\"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/896.png\\",\\"color\\":\\"white\\",\\"isLegendary\\":true,\\"isMythical\\":false}"]',
  pc: '[null]'
}
```

Now, Using the `mysql2` npm package I want to get the name of a pokemon, and if it's found, return that pokemon object. I add the pokemons to the database like this:

```
  await (
    await con
  ).query(
    `UPDATE profileSchema SET pokemons = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(pokemons, '$', '${JSON.stringify(
      pokemon
    )}') WHERE id = '${interaction.user.id}'`
  );
```

How can I search a pokemon by its name where the id is equal to the one i input? Something like `SELECT profileSchema WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(pokemons, name) WHERE id = 'id I input'`? I am new to sql and any help is appreciated!

Comment: There's no such thing as a "JSON Array". JSON is a string format. When it's JSON, it's a string. When you parse the JSON, it gets turned back into JavaScript entities.

Comment: Can't it be used as an array? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html

Comment: Ok I made it by parsing the JSON string, which returns an array of JSON string, and to find the pokemon I parse every element of the array and check their name. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Maybe he store json string into database, if it so just do some filtering using LIKE